# I am getting no-module-found error in Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

Even after installing robotframework and robotframework-seleniumlibrary
libraries it is showing no module found error. If i do pip list i can see the library listed.

```
Unresolved library: Seleniumlibrary.
Error generating libspec:
Importing library 'Seleniumlibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No 
module named 'Seleniumlibrary'
Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting
and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.
```

[click here to see the code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvXB.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Is your VS  Codes set up to use that virtual env (venv)?

Comment: @SamMaksymyshyn yes, I have created a virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `SeleniumLibrary` (capital L) not `Seleniumlibrary` (lowercase l)

Comment: i have tried both. It does not work.

Comment: @MilanSingh: please update your question with the exact error you get when you use the correct name. Also, please show us how you installed the library, and how you're calling your test script.